# How do I assign a method's value from the method's class to a new class?

Tags: java

So, I have an assignment which tells me that I need to write an accesor method which will assign the return value of a method in a different class to this new accessor method. Problem is, I have no idea how I do this.

This is the part of the code, where the method I want to call in the Forest class, the method itself would for example be public int GetValue().

```
public class Tree {
  private int value;

  public Tree(int inputValue){
    value = inputValue;
  }

  public int getValue(){
    return value;
  }
}
```

Below here is the part of the code example where I want to call the value from the getValue() method.

```
public class Forest {
  private Tree valueINeed;

    public Forest(){

      public int getValueINeed() {
        valueINeed = Tree.getValue();

    }
```

I hope I have posted sufficient information and I look forward to your answers, thanks in advance!

Comment: This is confusing - `valueINeed` is of type `Tree`, but `getValue()` returns an `int`. I'd expect `int value = valueINeed.getValue()`, given that it's an *instance* method. Where are you creating an instance of `Tree` for `Forest.valueINeed`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I understand a bit better now. My confusion lies with the whole private Tree valueINeed. I don't understand that part in particular. If I write it as Tree, what difference does it makes compared? Thank you again good sir.

Comment: Well you're declaring a field - `Tree` is the type of the field, and `valueINeed` is the name. To be honest, SO isn't a good place to learn the very core parts of a programming language - I think you may be best off talking to your tutor (or whatever) - or read a good book on Java.

Comment: you can  start with books like `Head First Java` or `SCJP by Kathy Sierra` just  from the top of my head :)

Comment: Thing is, my tutor refuses to help me with the assignment, so I have to rely on help from external sources. Been trying to solve this since 11pm this morning :P

Comment: Anyways, thank you for your help much appreciated, I will try my best ^^

Comment: when you mark a variable as `private` it means that you cannot access that value directly even with a reference to that instance. So in your case if you have `Tree tree = new Tree(); tree.value;` will throw a compiler error. Actually your `getValueINeed()` will throw a compiler error because your're trying to call `getValue()` on Tree but that method is not static

Comment: You've made more sense than anyone who's written anything on the entire internet today. I just ask you one favor, can you please show what the updated version of the code would look like?

Comment: Haha.. it's not like that there are tons of materials out there to help you on this but if you don't know what you're searching for, it's like searching for a needle in a haystack even with google ;)

Comment: I've tried so many different stack overflow questions, but they all just seems so confusing and not relative to what I need done.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public class Forest{
    private int valueINeed;

    public Forest() {
    }

    public int getValueINeed(){
        valueINeed = (new Tree(5)).getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have attempted your suggestion, which is much appreciated. But it now prompts me an error which says: "incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Tree".

Comment: Yes, if you change valueINeed's datatype to int, it'll work,I've edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Forest {
    private int valueINeed;

    /* default no-arg constructor, you can even skip this one 
       compiler will create one for you if you don't write one*/
    public Forest(){

    }

    public int getValueINeed(){
        // invoke tree constructor with int argument
        Tree tree = new Tree(5);
        valueINeed = tree.getValue();
        return valueINeed;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling it's really close to working, but it's prompting me a "missing return statement". Is it not actually taking the value from the Tree class?

Comment: You sir, you right there behind the screen. You're the kind of guy who makes life worth living. Someone finally explained this concept to me after 8 hours of staring into the screen. I appreciate it so much!

Comment: Glad to be of help. I strongly recommend you to read one of those books, head first is easy to digest, so start with that so that you don't have to waste so much time on simple things :) If my post answers your question, feel free to up vote and accept